# Implement a function named as flip; which will take a number as input and flip its last N digits

Tags: c, function

when I try to call the function as flip(flip(num,no),no). I am getting an answer of flip(num, no) and I can't find the solution of this code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int flip(int number, int n);
main()
{
    int num = 12345;

    int no = 3;
    int result = flip(flip(num,no), no);
    printf("%d", result);
}
int flip(int number, int n)
{
    int x = number % 10;
    int s = n + x * pow(10, n - 1);
    int temp = n * pow(10, n - 1) + x;
    int sum = number + s - temp;
    int* ptr = &sum;
    return *ptr;
}
```

> Required Answer = 12345;
>
> Output = 12543;

Comment: `int* ptr = &sum; return *ptr;` can be written as `return sum;`

Comment: I would begin to debug only `flip(num, no)`

Comment: I think you need some loop.

Comment: `pow` means potential issues due to floating point conversion, don't use it.

Comment: if the function `flip` should flip the n-th digit with the first one. It is implemented wrongly. So the invariant `x = flip(flip(x,n),n)` can't be true. Kindly asking is this somekind of assigment?

Comment: Try `11911` as input and you see that is is cleary wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With loop, you can handle digit by digit:

```
int flip(int number, int n)
{
    int rev = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i != n; ++i) {
        rev *= 10;
        rev += number % 10;
        number /= 10;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i != n; ++i) {
        number *= 10;
    }
    return number + rev;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/dSjk6D)